# Regex to fetch number from bracket?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to fetch numbers from [55,66] and trying to store in variable in c# them.

I am able to fetch like 55,66 but not able to fetch 55 66

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Comment: Thanks for advice i am here for first time.

Comment: just show your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok since it's a nice question, i'll provide the answer. In regex, this could be possible only through [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). The anchor `\G` matches at the position where the previous match ended.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?:\[|(?<!^)\G),?(\d+)(?=[^\[\]]*\])");
```

**Code:**

```
String input = @"fo bar [55,66,67,748,484] buz 234 456";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?:\[|(?<!^)\G),?(\d+)(?=[^\[\]]*\])");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/gza3JZ)

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT0cE5/2)